# Testing Implementation Details (React Testing Library)

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I have a project with a functional component which basically consist of a useEffect that makes calls to an API and depends on state changes. This is basically a behind-the-scenes file that does all the work while my other components actually hold the code for user interaction and DOM manipulation.
My question is: how do i test state changes within the behind-the-scenes file? I know react testing library goes against implementation details BUT it feels weird to just let them go untested. Is there any work around for this? Switching from enyzme to RTL.

Comment: You'll have to mock the api (I'd recommend msw) and then await from the DOM udpates making use of the `waitFor` method. But it's hard to tell more without your component code.

Comment: I wouldn't bother test implementation details. Perhaps for complex and important components, but it's often not worth the time.